# Matplotlib - Transformation between figure and image coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have data I wish to do some manipulations on, which are easier to do if I convert my data to an image (e.g., Hough transform). For that, I convert the data to an image (see attached figure). However, I do not understand how to properly move between the two coordinate systems (or alternatively, convert the axes instance to image rather than the figure instance, and then transformation would be trivial).

I tried playing around with the [transformations framework](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) but with no success.

I attach a figure containing two subplots, on the left of the scatter data, and on the right its image representation.

(also, I don't know if how I turned the scatter data to an image can be done neater, if so, I would be happy to hear suggestions for improvement).

I use python 3.6.9; matplotlib version = 3.3.4

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- Study case: generate random data
X = np.random.rand(1000, 2)

# --- Figure configuration
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 25))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

# --- First subplot
ax1.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=2, c='k')
ax1.set_title('ax.scatter')

# --- Scatter plot to image
Fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(Fig)
Ax = Fig.gca()
Ax.axis('off')
Ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=2, c='k')
Ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
Ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
canvas.draw()  # draw the canvas, cache the renderer
width, height = Fig.get_size_inches() * Fig.get_dpi()
height = int(height)
width = int(width)
img = np.frombuffer(canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8').reshape(height, width, 3)

# --- Display image
ax2.imshow(img)
plt.title('ax.imshow')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When you call imshow set the “extent” kwarg and then the transform is 1:1

Comment: Extent will match the tick labels, but the data will remain misaligned, as in the figure.